# Overriding multiple global variables with ContextManager

Tags: python, contextmanager

Is there a utility/pattern to override multiple global variables within a context in Python 2.7? IE something like

```
var1 = someval
var2 = someotherval
with my_context(var1=newval1, var2=newval2,...):
  print var1   # prints newval1
```

Comment: Yikes ... Global state that you want to mutate?  I doubt that this exists because it doesn't seem like something most people would want...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but the fact that it's [`unittest.mock.patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#the-patchers) should tell you something about what this is intended to be used for:

```
import unittest.mock

with unittest.mock.patch('module.thing', replacement_thing):
    do_whatever()
```

If you want to patch several things in the same call, you can use [`unittest.mock.patch.multiple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-multiple):

```
from unittest.mock import patch

with patch.multiple(module, thing1=replacement_thing, thing2=other_thing):
    # module.thing1 and module.thing2 are now patched
    do_whatever()
```

Just make sure none of the things you want to patch happen to collide with the argument names of that function (`target`, `spec`, `create`, `spec_set`, `autospec`, or `new_callable`). If they do, fall back to the regular `patch`.

If you want to do this for non-unit-testing purposes, you may want to reconsider your design.

If you're on Python 2 and `unittest.mock` isn't in the standard library, you can download the [backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock) from PyPI. This one is called `mock` rather than `unittest.mock`.

Comment: Consider using `unittest.mock.patch.multiple` instead, which seems to do exactly what the OP wants.

Comment: @ppperry: Oh, huh. I didn't know that was a thing! Thanks for the tip.

Comment: And I suppose that `patch.dict` could be used to patch `globals()` in the current module if necessary ...